# DB2 SQL point in time data on a transactional table

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to extract point in time information from a history table.  The table contains fld_nbr which maps to attributes such as job codes, employee status, work location, etc.  How can I find what an employee's status is as of a particular date.  The data might show

```
Employee# fld_nbr beg_date value 
1234      19      10/1/16  AA
1234      14      10/1/16  40
1234      14      1/6/17   46
1234      19      9/15/17  LA
```

I need to find what the status (fld_nbr 19) and location (fld_nbr 14) was on 1/1/17.  I would expect my result set to be fld_nbr 19 = AA and fld_nbr 14 = 40.

EDIT Here is what I ended up with:

```
WITH MO1 AS
(SELECT AFF.AFFILIATE, COUNT(HIS.EMPLOYEE) AS MO1_HC
 FROM
(SELECT HIST.COMPANY, HIST.EMPLOYEE, EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE, EMP.TERM_DATE, 
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 14 THEN A_VALUE END) AS PROCESS_LEVEL,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 14 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS PL_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 15 THEN A_VALUE END) AS DEPARTMENT,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 15 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS DEPT_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 20 THEN A_VALUE END) AS EMP_STATUS,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 20 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS STATUS_DATE,
DAYS(DATE('2017-10-31')) - DAYS(EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE) AS DOS
FROM DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRHRHISTORY HIST
INNER JOIN (SELECT EMPLOYEE, FLD_NBR, MAX(BEG_DATE) AS MostRecent 
                     FROM DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRHRHISTORY 
                     WHERE BEG_DATE < DATE('2017-10-31') 
                     AND COMPANY = 207
                     AND FLD_NBR IN (14, 15, 20)
                     GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, FLD_NBR) AS tA ON HIST.EMPLOYEE = tA.EMPLOYEE
                                                           AND HIST.FLD_NBR = tA.FLD_NBR
                                                           AND HIST.BEG_DATE = tA.MostRecent
INNER JOIN DATAMGMT.VW_GCHREMPLOYEE EMP ON HIST.EMPLOYEE = EMP.EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE BETWEEN DATE('2017-10-31') - 365 DAYS AND DATE('2017-10-31') 
AND SUBSTR(HIST.A_VALUE, 1, 1) NOT IN ('T', 'Z')
GROUP BY HIST.COMPANY, HIST.EMPLOYEE, EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE, EMP.TERM_DATE) AS HIS
INNER JOIN DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRAFFILIATE AFF ON AFF.COMPANY = HIS.COMPANY AND AFF.PROCESS_LEVEL = HIS.PROCESS_LEVEL AND AFF.DEPARTMENT = HIS.DEPARTMENT
WHERE HIS.EMP_STATUS IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AFF.AFFILIATE),
MO2 AS
(SELECT AFF.AFFILIATE, COUNT(HIS.EMPLOYEE) AS MO2_HC
 FROM
(SELECT HIST.COMPANY, HIST.EMPLOYEE, EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE, EMP.TERM_DATE, 
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 14 THEN A_VALUE END) AS PROCESS_LEVEL,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 14 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS PL_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 15 THEN A_VALUE END) AS DEPARTMENT,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 15 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS DEPT_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 20 THEN A_VALUE END) AS EMP_STATUS,
MAX(CASE WHEN HIST.FLD_NBR = 20 THEN BEG_DATE END) AS STATUS_DATE,
DAYS(DATE('2017-10-31') - 1 MONTH) - DAYS(EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE) AS DOS
FROM DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRHRHISTORY HIST
INNER JOIN (SELECT EMPLOYEE, FLD_NBR, MAX(BEG_DATE) AS MostRecent 
                     FROM DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRHRHISTORY 
                     WHERE BEG_DATE < DATE('2017-10-31') - 1 MONTH
                     AND COMPANY = 207
                     AND FLD_NBR IN (14, 15, 20)
                     GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, FLD_NBR) AS tA ON HIST.EMPLOYEE = tA.EMPLOYEE
                                                           AND HIST.FLD_NBR = tA.FLD_NBR
                                                           AND HIST.BEG_DATE = tA.MostRecent
INNER JOIN DATAMGMT.VW_GCHREMPLOYEE EMP ON HIST.EMPLOYEE = EMP.EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE BETWEEN DATE('2017-10-31') - 1 MONTH - 365 DAYS AND DATE('2017-10-31') - 1 MONTH
AND SUBSTR(HIST.A_VALUE, 1, 1) NOT IN ('T', 'Z')
GROUP BY HIST.COMPANY, HIST.EMPLOYEE, EMP.ANNIVERS_DATE, EMP.TERM_DATE) AS HIS
INNER JOIN DATAMGMT.VW_GCHRAFFILIATE AFF ON AFF.COMPANY = HIS.COMPANY AND AFF.PROCESS_LEVEL = HIS.PROCESS_LEVEL AND AFF.DEPARTMENT = HIS.DEPARTMENT
WHERE HIS.EMP_STATUS IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AFF.AFFILIATE)
SELECT MO1.AFFILIATE, MO1.MO1_HC, MO2.MO2_HC
FROM MO1
INNER JOIN MO2 ON MO2.AFFILIATE = MO1.AFFILIATE
```

Comment: There is an excellent blog Fun with date ranges - which also fits to the answer from Used_By_Already - here http://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=672

Comment: Thank you all for the help!  I actually have uses for all of the samples and am very appreciative! I have edited my original post to show what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, which will give you the point in time record for each employee/fld_nbr combination (I forget the syntax for DB2 date literals, you might need to play with that):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl INNER JOIN (SELECT Employee#, fld_nbr, MAX(beg_date) AS MostRecent
                     FROM tbl
                     WHERE beg_date < #1/1/17#
                     GROUP BY Employee#, fld_nbr) AS tA ON tbl.Employee# = tA.Employee#
                                                           AND tbl.fld_nbr = tA.fld_nbr
                                                           AND tbl.beg_date = tA.MostRecent
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found another snag that I was hoping you could help with.  There is a SEQ_NBR field that is used for transactions that occur on the same date.  I need to pull the max date and SEQ_NBR.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I did just that!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest massage the data to reflect date ranges using `LEAD()` then it becomes simple to isolate which values applied on any single date.

```
select
*
from (
    select
        employee
      , fld_nbr
      , beg_date
      , coalesce(lead(beg_date,1) over(partition by Employee, fld_nbr order by beg_date), current date) end_date
    from table1
    ) d
where beg_date <= date('2017-01-01')
and end_date > date('2017-01-01')
```

e.g.

```
| employee | fld_nbr |             beg_date |             end_date |
|----------|---------|----------------------|----------------------|
|     1234 |      14 | 2016-10-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-06T00:00:00Z |
|     1234 |      19 | 2016-10-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-09-15T00:00:00Z |
```

nb: my example was written using TSQL so my DB2 syntax might be a little off

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b5cbc/1)